# Is there a better way to index a column with very few unique values?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I have a table called `posts`, and three of the columns are `category`, `type` and `createTime`. This `category` column only has 10 unique values, and `type` only has 4 unique values across the records. What is the best way to create index for these columns?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "posts" 
(
    /* other fields */
    "type" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "category" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "createTime" BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
);
```

Here are two of my most used queries, including its indexes:

```
/* 1. Search posts based on category */
CREATE INDEX "posts_category_createTime_idx" ON "posts"("category", "createTime" DESC);

SELECT *
FROM "posts"
WHERE "category" = 'funny'
ORDER BY "createTime" DESC
LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0


/* 2. Search posts based on type */
CREATE INDEX "posts_type_createTime_idx" ON "posts"("type", "createTime" DESC);

SELECT *
FROM "posts"
WHERE "type" = 'fresh'
ORDER BY "createTime" DESC
LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0
```

Is this the most I can do in postgres in terms of optimization?

What I tried: Basic index implementation to get the optimized query

What I expect: Find the best approach to get the most out of postgres in my scenarios

Comment: Since these queries return no rows, the most efficient solution is not to run them. If these are not your real queries, how shall we help? The ideal indexes depend on a) how large the tables are b) how fast the queries have to be.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe could u elaborate on "return no rows"?

Comment: My mistake. I misread the 8 for a 0. Still, it would be important to have the additional information.

Comment: Are those queries not extremely fast already?  They said be. `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` could answer that.

Comment: You told us what you tried and what you expect, but what did you get (ie timing)? And what are the data columns?